# Implement Spring batch circuit breaker

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I am building a Spring batch job and in the Item processor step I am consuming an external end-point and saving the values to DB. The external point at times is very slow and takes more than 60 sec to respond. So, as a work around I implemented `restTemplate` timeout(15s) but, how to implement circuit breaker techniques here. As a result of this my transaction is timing out (even after implementing timeout). Are there any solutions to overcome this out of box in spring-batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to implement circuit breaker techniques here

You can annotate the `ItemProcessor#process` with `@CircuitBreaker` (see attributes like `maxAttempts`, `resetTimeout`, etc) from the [spring-retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) library and add a recovery method that you annotate with `@Recover`.

Michael Minella gives a complete sample of this very scenario in his talk: [Cloud Native Batch Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NZVwv1cmMc). And you can find the code example [here](https://github.com/mminella/cloud-native-batch/blob/3a4722189ba8a6c6a29a75f18e9118d1befd1932/batch-job/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/EnrichmentProcessor.java).